# Are there any characters that can be encoded in UTF-16 but not UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, utf-16

Are there any characters that can be encoded in UTF-16 but not UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

UTF-* are encodings that can encode the full range of Unicode characters.
The differences between the encodings are how many bytes each character uses.

Comment: In fact, UTF-8 can physically encode many more codepoints (U+0000 - U+7FFFFFFF) than UTF-16 can physically encode (U+0000 - U+10FFFF). UTF-8 originally defined 5-byte and 6-byte formats for such high codepoints, but was later restricted to encode only the same codepoints that UTF-16 can encode for compatibility, thus restricting it to 4 bytes max, higher codepoints are illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the length of result and compatibility (utf-8 may easily be integrated with old ASCII-based software and utf-16 - with Win32 Unicode application). Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 represent short encoding of Unicode.